# Поиск по минимальному эвклидовому расстоянию между заданным вектором и векторами в БД

Tags: sql, алгоритм, postgresql, математика, postgis

В таблице PostgreSQL в поле типа double[] хранятся векторы высокой размерности (128 координат если быть точным).

```
 create table tab (
   id integer, 
   name character varying(200)
   vector double precision[]
 )
```

По заданному вектору нужно вернуть из БД одну запись с минимальным эвклидовым расстоянием между этим вектором и вектором в записи таблицы.

Имеется функция которая вычисляет эвклидово расстояние двух векторов по всем известной формуле `SQRT((v1[1]-v2[1])^2+(v1[2]-v2[2])^2+....+(v1[128]-v2[128])^2)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.euclidian(
  arr1 double precision[],
  arr2 double precision[])
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
  select sqrt(SUM(tab.v)) as euclidian from (SELECT 
     UNNEST(vec_sub(arr1,arr2)) as v) as tab;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

Вспомогательная функция:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.vec_sub(
  arr1 double precision[],
  arr2 double precision[])
RETURNS double precision[] AS
$BODY$
  SELECT array_agg(result)
    FROM (SELECT (tuple.val1 - tuple.val2)*(tuple.val1 - tuple.val2) 
        AS result
        FROM (SELECT UNNEST($1) AS val1
               ,UNNEST($2) AS val2
               ,generate_subscripts($1, 1) AS ix) tuple
    ORDER BY ix) inn;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

Запрос :

```
select tab.id as tabid, tab.name as tabname, 
        euclidian(target_vector,tab.vector) as eucl from tab 
order by eulc ASC
limit 1
```

Пока всё отлично работает. 
Но нетрудно заметить, что запрос может быть выполнен не иначе как полным перебором всех записей в таблице tab. До определенного момента это всех устраивало, но сейчас база данных подрастает и встает вопрос что полный перебор не очень хорош мягко говоря. Сейчас в базе несколько тысяч записей и явных проблем с производительностью пока нет, но десятки и сотни тысяч записей не за горами.

Вопрос - как можно изловчиться и обеспечить индексный поиск в таблице tab при выполнении запроса? Чтобы хотя бы 90% ненужных записей отбрасывалось по индексу, а в оставшихся 10% уже допустимо полным перебором пройти.

P.S. одно из текущих направлений поиска решения: расширение [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html) позволяет вести поиск и сортировку по расстоянию (ST_3DDistance), фильтр по удаленности (ST_3DWithin) и пр. в 3-х мерном пространстве - делается это быстро по индексам. Может быть как-то кто-то это абстрагировал на случай N-мерного пространства?

P.S.2. данные <s>метеорологических</s> наблюдений:

- сделал запрос select max(val), min(val) from (select unnest(vector)
  as val from tab) as tab1 - 0.485470712185 -0.41735497117 - я точно не
  знаю, думаю значения координат в теории не превышают 1.0 по модулю
- при этом векторы не нормализованы, расстояние от (0,0,...0) лежит в
  пределах от 1.2 до 1.6.

P.S.3. Подобную задачу не первый раз решаю - предыдущий раз это было связано с поиском ближайшей точки в облаке точек (3D), но там у меня было все локально в памяти (база данных iBoxDB), там даже и не рыпался от полного перебора уйти... а тут вся мощь сервера postgresql - из принципа хочется решить).

P.S.4. Исходя из данных наблюдений, максимальное расстояние между точками (на основании имеющейся статистики) составляет примерно 3.2 - расширим на всякий случай до 5, ну или до 10. Мне точно не интересны точки, отдаленные друг от друга более чем на 1.0. Выделим из 128-мерного пространства несколько (сколько не жалко, скажем 10,20) трехмерных проекций - наборов координат (v1,v2,v3), (v4,v5,v6), и т.д. Очевидно, если в одной из трехмерных проекций расстояние превысило лимит (1.0) - то меньшим на полном наборе координат оно точно уже не станет. Далее пытаемся применить то что есть в PostGIS - индексируем каждую их трехмерных проекций векторов и затем при поиске ставим фильтры с помощью ST_3DWithin < 1.0 (количество фильтров будет равно количеству выделенных трехмерных проекций). Стоит попробовать в новогоднюю ночь :-) Очень бы хотелось компетентный комментарий гуру по PostGIS - случится ли чудо в новогоднюю ночь, или можно спокойно веселиться? :-)

P.S.5. В сторону buckets предлагаю больше не копать - во первых их ну ооочень много получится, как не раскидывай - даже если строить на проекции а не на полной размерности, скажем взять первых 64 координаты и раскидать по букетам (<0,>=0) - получится 18446744073709551616 возможных букетов - куда тут... Во вторых, есть проблема границ букетов - точки могут находиться на минимальном расстоянии но попасть в соседние букеты, это нада учитывать в запросах, для этого нужно держать диаграмму соседей для каждого букета... если же применять простейшее разбиение (<0,>=0) - оно в принципе теряет всякий смысл, потому что для одной оси граница только одна и нужно все равно искать и там и там... а если разбивать каждую ось на 4 диапазона - количество букетов уверенно уйдёт в бесконечность... В третьих, не хотелось бы создавать велосипед с помощью напильника - если ГИС-системы решают задачу на трехмерных координатах - либо абстрагировать эти механизмы на большие размерности, либо выделять 3х мерные проекции и пытаться индексировать на них.

Comment: а наличие базы обязательно? Тут диаграмма воронова напрашивается, но как сделать именно в БД триангляцию Делоне я не знаю. И не уверен что получится.

Comment: именно в базе данных нужно - столько записей загонять в диаграмму в памяти, перестраивать диаграмму при добавлении/удалении - нереально

Comment: I have one word for you: buckets.

Comment: @pavel самое интересное что я придумал - проиндексировать по расстоянию между нулевой точкой и точкой заданной координатами в таблице, потом вычислить расстояние между нулевой точкой и вектором в запросе, и взять записи по диапазону (меня не интересуют точки которые дальше 0.5 друг от друга) но это даст оптимизацию процентов 10-20 вместо желаемых 90 :-) должно быть еще что-то... объявлю пожалуй конкурс через пару дней

Comment: @Igor разобрался с width_bucket - интересная функция, но ей бы индексированное поле на входе бы... а как быть в моем случае не знаю даже, или вы что-то другое имели в виду? какое-то сегментирование просится применить, но не приходит ничего конкретного... с направлениями и углами в 128-мерном пространстве просто жжжж...уть :-)

Comment: Если у вас есть понимание, как выглядит сама структура данных по которой можно эффективно искать - то посмотрите в сторону написание своего `extension` индексного поиска через `gist` фреймворк: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-extensibility.html

Comment: "сэкономить вычисление квадратного корня" - Евгений, это не ценное предложение, а фигня. Я отказываюсь поверить, что для человека, решающего задачи такого уровня, эта "оптимизация" не является очевидной/тривиальной.

Comment: @Igor ну в общем да, я такой прием часто использую для магнитуды трехмерных точек, но тут и правда самому не пришло ))

Comment: простите, чисто из любопытства, а каково практическое применение этой задачи?

Comment: @Anatol ну это поиск похожих объектов по набору признаков, нетрудно догадаться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть [методики понижения размерности](https://ru.coursera.org/learn/unsupervised-learning/lecture/y5Nxe/ponizhieniie-razmiernosti), когда из N измерений делается два или три. Например:

- [Independent Component Analysis](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/whatisica.shtml) (ICA)
- [Principal Component Analysis (PCA)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html)
- [Nonnegative Matrix Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) (NMF)

Известны и [многие другие способы подойти к проблеме излишнего числа измерений](http://ru.learnmachinelearning.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). В том числе можно посмотреть на [алгоритмы кластеризации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Не обязательно на ваших данных любой из этих алгоритмов будет работать хорошо, но какой-то может дать приемлемые результаты.

Другое дело что вы далеко не уедете, считая ваши данные непрозрачными. Вам хорошо бы понять, какие координаты что означают. Наверняка ж эти векторы не из случайных чисел. Скорее всего вы берете их из предпоследнего слоя нейронной сети. Значит можно для какой-то известной выборки, которая кардинально отличается по какому-то фактору, можно выяснить какой нейрон соответствует этому фактору. И вот у вас уже одна из координат для трехмерного вектора, по которому можно быстро искать.

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ! О некоторых наблюдениях за данными я сообщал, в целом смысл их понятен - это набор неких свойств (несколько нормализованных) некого объекта - а если точнее, дифференциальных свойств контура объекта (детально описать увы не имею права). Данные берутся не из нейросети, к слову - нейросеть могла бы решать подобную задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Это, скорее, комментарий, а не ответ, но в комментарий он не поместился.

Тут я вижу два направления - куда копать. Первое - "buckets" из PostgreSQL. Не могу сказать точно, насколько они сюда подходят, - я сам ими не пользовался, только читал. Второе - старые добрые ячейки для нахождения точки из набора, ближайшей к данной точке. Делим Ваш 128-мерный мир на кубики. Размер кубика будет зависеть от диапазонов координат, кубики могут быть параллелепипедами. Все кубики пронумерованы - номер кубика может быть вычислен из его индексов по всем 128-и осям (индексы по осям находятся простым делением). Все точки заранее распределяем по кубикам. Находим, в какой кубик попадает данная точка. Многое зависит от равномерности распределения точек в пространстве. Вычислять [квадрат] расстояния можно только для точек в том же кубике или в в нем и кубиках его окружающих (их, правда, будет три в 128-й степени).

*Update*

> Мне точно не интересны точки, отдаленные друг от друга более чем на
>   1.0.

Это отличное условие для предварительной выборки:

```
WHERE ABS(v1[1]-v2[1]) < 1 AND ABS(v1[2]-v2[2]) < 1 AND ... AND ABS(v1[128]-v2[128]) < 1
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ - даже Maple запустил чтобы вычислить - 3^128 = 11790184577738583171520872861412518665678211592275841109096961 :-)))))

Comment: в 3-х мерном пространстве можно сегментировать по азимуту - делится сфера на N угловых сегментов (типа мячик для гольфа), вычисляется в какой сегмент попадает вектор - вот они buckets, количество сегментов можно свести к нескольким сотням или тысячам, в зависимости от желаемой точности, что вполне разумно. Но если у нас размерность 128... это просто абзац так просегментировать...

Comment: для сегментирования 128-мерного пространства по четвертям понадобится 2^128 букетов, что составляет "всего" 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 - но уже чуточку легче )))

Comment: @EugeneBartosh диапазоны возможных значений по измерениям заранее известны? они величины одного порядка?

Comment: сделал запрос select max(val), min(val) from (select unnest(vector) as val from tab) as tab1 - 0.485470712185 -0.41735497117 -  я точно не знаю, думаю они в теории не превышают 1.0 по модулю

Comment: при этом векторы не нормализованы, расстояние от (0,0,...0) лежит в пределах от 1.2 до 1.6

Comment: АЛСО, сегментирование по угловым или пространственным букетам имеет неприятную особенность - минимально отдаленные точки могут попасть в разные букеты только потому, что граница случайно пролегла между ними...

Comment: @EugeneBartosh да, есть у него такой минус

Comment: @EugeneBartosh можно хранить не все кубики а только те где есть значения, а это СУЩЕСТВЕННО меньше. И хранить не в многомерной матрице, а просто в одномерном массиве.

Comment: @EugeneBartosh кроме того кубики можно делать не фиксированого размера, а размер адаптировать под плотность. То есть если в некотором квадранте много точек, то этот квадрант разбиваем на подквадраты. То есть получится дерево.

Answer (score 2):

Можно делить на кубики не равномерно а адаптивно, и хранить не все кубики а только те что содержат элементы.

Например если в кубик входит несколько элементов, например больше 15, то тогда дробим его на части.

Получается массив кубиков разного размера, либо дерево кубиков.

Тогда алгоритм решения будет таким. Ищем самый маленький куб в который входит элемент, эта операция где-то между константой по сложности и логарифмической сложностью, если вектора будет концентрироваться в одной точке. И уже дальше проверяем только элементы из этого кубика и соседних (на случай если вектор находится рядом с границей кубика).

**Обновлено:**

Но тут возникает проблема с соседними квадратами.... Дело в том что в плоскости соседей - 8, в 3-х мерном пространстве 26... а в 128-ми мерном, их будет очень много.

В этой ситуации можно сделать так, рассчитать минимальное расстояние до края, если из найденных расстояний в этом же кубе расстояние меньше чем до ближайшего края то вектор найден. Если же край ближе, тогда уже ищем по соседям или полным перебором.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я свои соображения по кубикам (букетам) изложил выше (см. P.S.5) - для трехмерного пространства вероятно так и нужно решать, бить пространство на N каких-то областей, при этом N можно сделать адаптивным от количества данных, и плотность кубиков можно сделать неравномерной - для случая 3D всё это выльется в довольно сложный алгоритм (что-то вроде Воронова), но когда 128D - ну просто ну никак...