# сортировка изображений

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, opencv, обработка-изображений

Сравнил попарно все изображения - получается матрица чисел (для удобства сжаты до 0-254) N x N, как теперь упорядочить чтобы похожие были рядом т.е

```
int r[][] = {
    { 255, 100,  93 },
    { 100, 255, 113 },
    {  93, 113, 255 }};
```

в этом примере вроде бы правильный порядок of = 1,0,2. n-число изобр. будет меньше 100000, числа в массиве это насколько различны изображения т.е 1 строка 0/0(такие особый случай = 255), 0 и 1, 0 и 2..

1 вариант, функция поиска ищет максимально похожее место вставки;
работает совсем не плохо, лучше чем полный перебор. На длинной дистанции результат вообще интересный получился, как preview или нарезка. Лучше бы конечно если 1 куском непрерывно было, а так надо соединять на границах получившиеся сцены (баг или сравнение не точное)

```
of.push_back(0);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    auto find_bm = [&](int j) {
        std::pair<int, int> m = { 0, 255 };
        for (int i = 0; i < of.size(); i++)
        {
            int _1 = of[i], x = r[j][_1],
                _2, y = x;
            if (i < of.size() - 1)
                _2 = of[i + 1], y = r[j][_2];
            if (m.second > x + y)
                m = { i, x + y };
        }
        return of.begin() + m.first + 1;
    };
    auto it = find_bm(i);
    of.emplace(it, i);
}
```

создание матрицы, код слишком интегрирован, надеюсь понятно так:

```
srcc = avs_vfbuf_t(new avs_vfbuf(_srcc, env));
cv::Ptr<cv::img_hash::ImgHashBase> func = cv::img_hash::BlockMeanHash::create();
std::vector<cv::Mat> img_hash(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    avs_vf_t srcf = srcc->get(i);
    s_vf_plane srcp = srcf->plane();
    cv::Mat img(srcp.h, srcp.w, CV_8U, srcp.p(), srcp.pitch);
    func->compute(img, img_hash[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        r[i][j] = r[j][i] = std::min(int(func->compare(img_hash[i], img_hash[j])), 254);
}
```

такой вариант не работает больше чем с ~15 размером, и я не уверен что вообще правильно:

```
int of[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> bm = { INT32_MAX, of };
do
{
    int _ = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        _ += r[of[i - 1]][of[i]];
    if (_ < bm.first)
        bm = { _, of };
} while (std::next_permutation(of.begin(), of.end()));
of = bm.second;
```

Answer (score 3):

Побитовое сравнение изображений - это сродни по-атомному сравнению двух людей с целью понять похожи они или нет. И первый и второй случай не имеют смысла и будут работать только для абсолютно одинаковых объектов. 
Представьте - камера сняла кадр, потом сместилась на пару сантиметров (или повернулась на пару градусов) и тут же сняла второй кадр. Похожи будут картинки? Вне всякого сомнения, любой кто взглянет скажет "одинаковые", если не особо вглядываться. А побитовое сравнение даст полную туфту - никаких совпадений. 
Так же как и по-атомное сравнение двух близнецов даст какую-то туфту - один простыл, другой что-то не то съел, и у них будет минимум совпадений, хотя они очень-очень похожи внешне.

Есть множество приемов сравнения изображений - на основе цветового баланса (гистограммы), на основе характеристик контуров, на основе ключевых точек, и так далее. 
Самым распространенным (но не самым лучшим) является метод сопоставления ключевых точек - подробно с примерами [в документации opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html).

Comment: не, качаство то вполне. проблема не в сравнении а сортировке/упорядочивании. я пробовал несколько способов и получается плохо. самое лучшее полный перебор или - еще добавлю старый способ. главное в вопросе "чтобы похожие были рядом", остальное не так важно

Comment: не знаю что там у вас получается и что для вас хорошо )) чтобы найти просто более менее похожие - считайте N средних цветов (получите для каждой картинки гистограмму, вектор размерности N) и сравнивайте векторы например методом минимального эвклидового расстояния.

Comment: да нахожу я их)), кстати через img_hash opencv, только после получается что 1 например похожа на 2 и на 3 но 3 на 2 нет, или что-то вроде того, я даже причину пока не понял, нужно рассортировать "по возрастанию")

Comment: гм, в вашем коде ничего такого я не увидел, не увидел в частности вычисления эвклидового расстояния. С img_hash вы это переборщили - начните с простого, так как с opencv вы очевидно недавно только познакомились... calcHist подойдет - https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html

Comment: Получше (поновее) статья - https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html
Вот еще готовый пример на питоне - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/

Comment: img_hash проще наоборот - добавил код в вопрос,  там видно насколько все просто. качество пока нормальное и суть то пока не в этом а дальше. результат как я понял относительный, как их упорядочить то)

Comment: я писал здесь в том числе о проблемах поиска и сортировки по векторам признаков -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764135/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: легко можно найти картинки, похожие на какую-то конкретную... а отсортировать в принципе тоже легко, но неоднозначность имеется - картинка может быть похожа и на ту и на эту и еще на какую-то... например это лицо http://img.morphthing.com/i/40178073/2/0/add03860/Tom-Cruise--George-Clooney--Bruce-Willis.jpeg выдает 100% схожесь с томом крузом и брюсом уиллисом, хотя сами они друг на друга не похожи :-))

Comment: обычной сортировкой (как сортировка по строкам) по хешу или гистограмме пробовали? что-то удобоваримое?

Comment: не пробовал, так очень вероятно что не получится. это же хеш а не число

Comment: а вот по гистограмме может получиться более менее

Comment: все равно неоднозначность остается нужна сортировка, я еще более обдумал - пример если камера движется то -1 и +1 кадр похожи на 0 и очевидно их надо оставить как есть а получится -1 равен +1, т.е надо обдумать функцию поиска подходящей вставки. вообще рано сказал, надо пробовать...

Comment: вам нужно разбираться что это за хеш, я никогда не использовал img_hash поэтому не знаю как он формируется, а вы если хотите - то вот первоисточники - https://www.phash.org/docs/pubs/thesis_zauner.pdf :-)))

Comment: вам нужно написать отдельный вопрос, описать свой сценарий и попросить посоветовать наиболее подходящее решение, потому что приемов и их вариантов очень много - все сводится к выделению из изображений набора ключевых признаков, а вот что это за признаки - зависит от вашей задачи. В общем случае задачу поиска по набору признаков решается с помощью нейросети

Comment: я все еще думаю можно как-то использовать получившуюся матрицу сравнений, если сделать из нее максимально гладкий вектор - получится сортировка, наверное)

Comment: Vector is very glad (вектор очень гладкий :-)) Glad yourself please :-)) Какие только термины не выдумывают программисты, когда им приходится иметь дело с математикой - а вот нефиг было после универа всё забывать )) P.S. даёш глубокий треугольник и лохматый квадрат

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что вообще попытка преобразовать кучу изображений в линейный порядок с адекватным результатом не получится. Изображения я бы стал делить на группы схожести.

> такой вариант не работает больше чем с ~15 размером, и я не уверен что вообще правильно

Я вообще не понял что делает этот код. В случае уменьшения я бы попытался менять местами все изображения подряд и сохранять изменения. Однако на большом количестве изображений(как раз примерно 15) адекватной работы вряд ли удастся чего-то добиться.

И вдобавок зачем использовать int и сокращать его до 0-254 в таком уж случае логичнее uchar(хотя от этого скорость расчётов не увеличиться).

В общем советую подумать над разделением изображений на 5-10 групп схожести и потом уже их в линию. Вдобавок для создания матрицы 100 на 100 изображений надо очень много времени а на разделение на группы схожести куда меньше(не прийдётся полностью заполнять таблицу).

Comment: матрица создается быстро, и на 40000изобр. код уменьшает общую сумму разниц, неправильно думаю: например подбирается наиболее подходящяя пара и к ней дальше подходящая как вагоны, ошибка в  том что чуть меннее подходящая к начальной но всеравно нормальная таким образом может далеко уйти (наверное, а может и правильно работает)

Comment: на 40000 неверю ибо это 40*40 мб памяти матрица такую только на супер компе можно быстро заполнить. Если проблема в начале то создаём возможность добавления в начало. Но опятьже нельзя в линию выстроить адекватно изображения так. я бы лучше попытался разместить в объёме 3х а лучше 5 мерном, а потом в вектор преобразовать.

Comment: 2Гб это нормально (uint8_t), сложность квадратичная, так или иначе у меня ~15-25минут т.е за разумное время. Адекватно выстроить можно думаю, это матрица всетаки. Разделять на группы это запасной вариант - похожих кадров не больше 2 обычно, сортировать как-то придется потом

Comment: вы правы. уже писал, например это лицо img.morphthing.com/i/40178073/2/0/add03860/… выдает 100% схожесь с томом крузом и брюсом уиллисом, хотя сами они друг на друга не похожи :-) очень много критериев схожести... в каких-то случаях доминируют одни критерии, в других - другие

Comment: @EugeneBartosh тома первым эту посередине брюса после, вот так сортировку мне надо)

Comment: ну я бы вам тогда советовал отталкиваться от N эталонов - взять какие-то N картинок как эталоны, и отсортировать по эвклидовому расстоянию между векторами признаков между вашими картинками и каждым эталоном, взяв не более 10% самых близких... таким образом вы получите N букетов (buckets), затем объедините букеты с исключением дубликатов (типа оставить только варианты с самым близким расстоянием) - и вот индекс